# Error with latest ReactiveCocoa Carthage : No such module 'Result'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I'm updating my project to Swift 5 Xcode 10.3.

Everything was working fine with the previous Swift version now with the latest ReactiveCocoa 10.0.0

Already tried :

1. Deleting and updating all carthage
2. Deleting derivedData Folder, clean and build

[image]

Comment: - delete derivedData Folder, clean and build

Comment: That's the first and basic thing for iOS Developer :)

Answer (score 8):

Swift added its own `Result` type to the standard library in version 5. As such, `ReactiveSwift` [removed its dependency on the third-party `Result` library it had previously used](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600), and offers these instructions to update your code:

> - If you have used `Result` only as dependency of `ReactiveSwift`, remove all instances of `import Result`, `import enum Result.NoError` or `import struct Result.AnyError` and remove the `Result` Framework from your project.
> - Replace all cases where `NoError` was used in a `Signal` or `SignalProducer` with `Never`
> - Replace all cases where `AnyError` was used in a `Signal` or `SignalProducer` with `Swift.Error`

So for this particular error, just delete the `import Result` line.

Comment: Sorry @jjoelson i forgot to thank you for the answer

Answer (score -1):

Please do the following steps:-

1) Delete derived data.
2) Update  all Carthage.
3) Clean and build.